# How to split factor values in a column in R with different condition

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector like this.

```
> top[1:5,6]
[1] Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34 x 95 cm. (13 3/8 x 37 3/8 in.)    
[2] Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34.3 x 68.3 cm. (13 1/2 x 26 7/8 in.)
[3] Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 67 x 34 cm. (26 3/8 x 13 3/8 in.)    
[4] Scroll, mounted and framed, ink on paper \n 135 x 68 cm. (53 1/8 x 26 3/4 in.)              
[5] Hanging scroll, ink and colour on paper \n 80 x 28 cm. (31 1/2 x 11 in.)
```

This is some sample values of one column variable for my dataset and I want to split the column in the following way:

```
scroll   mounted and framed   ink and colour on paper   34 * 95 cm
```

and delete the ones in the brackets.

How can I achieve this as this is \n and comma as separator? At the very least, I want to have \n to separate the medium and size.

New to R, would appreciate any help

Comment: This would be fairly straightforward if you had hte same number of commas in each row but failing that it's a bit of a mess. You would need to take each case separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data <- c("Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34 x 95 cm. (13 3/8 x 37 3/8 in.)" , 
          "Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34.3 x 68.3 cm. (13 1/2 x 26 7/8 in.)" , 
          "Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 67 x 34 cm. (26 3/8 x 13 3/8 in.)" , 
          "Scroll, mounted and framed, ink on paper \n 135 x 68 cm. (53 1/8 x 26 3/4 in.)" , 
          "Hanging scroll, ink and colour on paper \n 80 x 28 cm. (31 1/2 x 11 in.)")


res <- strsplit(gsub("\\. *\\([^)]+\\)" , "" , data ) , ",|\n")

# [[1]]
# [1] "Scroll"                    " mounted and framed"       " ink and colour on paper " " 34 x 95 cm"              
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Scroll"                    " mounted and framed"       " ink and colour on paper " " 34.3 x 68.3 cm"          
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Scroll"                    " mounted and framed"       " ink and colour on paper " " 67 x 34 cm"              
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Scroll"              " mounted and framed" " ink on paper "      " 135 x 68 cm"       
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "Hanging scroll"            " ink and colour on paper " " 80 x 28 cm"
```

if you want data frame result

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(res, function(x) { as.data.frame(rbind(x)) }) , fill = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this result.

```
x <- "Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34 x 95 cm. (13 3/8 x 37 3/8 in.)"
strsplit(x, ", | \n | \\(.+")

#[[1]]
#[1] "Scroll"                  "mounted and framed"     
#[3] "ink and colour on paper" "34 x 95 cm."
```

Comment: You could also take care of the whitespaces within strsplit: `strsplit(x, ", | \n | \\(.+")`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example showed, we can remove the `\n` and the characters after the `(` with `gsub`.  Insert `,` based on the text showed using lookarounds and read the `vector` ('top1') with `read.table/read.csv`

```
top1 <- gsub('\\s*\\(.*$|[\n]', '', top)
read.table(text=gsub('(?<=(?i)scroll,)\\s+(?=ink)|(?<= on paper)\\s+',
  ',', top1, perl=TRUE), sep=',', header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#              V1                  V2                       V3              V4
#1         Scroll  mounted and framed  ink and colour on paper     34 x 95 cm.
#2         Scroll  mounted and framed  ink and colour on paper 34.3 x 68.3 cm.
#3         Scroll  mounted and framed  ink and colour on paper     67 x 34 cm.
#4         Scroll  mounted and framed             ink on paper    135 x 68 cm.
#5 Hanging scroll                      ink and colour on paper     80 x 28 cm.
```

#### data

```
top <- c('Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34 x 95 cm. (13 3/8 x 37 3/8 in.)',    
 'Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 34.3 x 68.3 cm. (13 1/2 x 26 7/8 in.)',
 'Scroll, mounted and framed, ink and colour on paper \n 67 x 34 cm. (26 3/8 x 13 3/8 in.)',   
 'Scroll, mounted and framed, ink on paper \n 135 x 68 cm. (53 1/8 x 26 3/4 in.)',             
 'Hanging scroll, ink and colour on paper \n 80 x 28 cm. (31 1/2 x 11 in.)')
```